# Python Regex: find all possible forms of a word in text with pattern

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I want to find all possible combinations of a list of words in a text (plural, singular, prefixed, etc.). Currently I defined the following function that uses a regex pattern to find a word in my text. But it doesn't match the word "nation" in the last sentence in my text (" who is a nation.") unless I replace the period with space (" who is a nation "). Similarly, it doesn't match the words "nationality" or "nations". I want to use a pattern so I can expand my code to match any words in a list of selected words in the text. Is there a way to check if these matchings exist in the text with a regex pattern?

```
text = '''
we are the natio 
we love other nations. 
other nationalities are good too, we are that. who is a nation.
'''

def WordsinSentence(word,sentence):    
    pattern = re.compile(' '+word+' |^'+word+' | '+word+' $')
#     stem = tokenize_and_stem(sentence)
#     stemmed_sent = ' '.join(stem)
    if re.search(pattern,sentence.lower()):
        return True
```

Comment: why not just split words by space, then check by `in` (Contains)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the regex 'findall' method to get all matches.

```py
def WordsinSentence(word,sentence):    
    pattern = re.compile(word)
    found = re.findall(pattern,sentence.lower())
    if found:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Learn more about it here: [Python Regex findall](https://pynative.com/python-regex-findall-finditer/)